# In R lm() regression fit, how handle a continuous effect and a ranged effect combined?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I want to know how to fit data into the `lm()` function in which one effect is continuous and the other effect takes place only on a range of the predictor.

Would the function (for example a ranged `x^2` effect) be similar to the following?

```
lm( y ~ x + x^2[x >= a & x <= b], mydata)
```

a and b are known since lm() is not a means to find the solution to them so after finding the range it should be plugged into the lm() function

Comment: is the `x^2` term set to zero outside of the range? (That's a funny statistical model, but OK ...) are `a` and `b` known in advance, or do they need to be estimated along with the coefficients (in which case this will be much harder and won't fit into `lm()`) ?

Comment: I'm guessing that the vertical bar is supposed to designate "and", not "or"? (i.e. you want *both* conditions to be true)?

Answer (score 3):

I think that

```
y ~ x+ I(x^2*(x>=a & x<=b))
```

ought to work, since the logical expression `(x>=a & x<=b)` should be coerced to numeric, hence 0 if `FALSE` and 1 if `TRUE` ...

I will make the unsolicited comment that this seems like a slightly weird model; unless you constrain it farther the fitted model will have discontinuous jumps in the mean at `x=a` and `x=b`.  It's possible, but not super-easy (and might or might not fit into `lm()`) to constrain it to be continuous at the boundary values ...

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to build such a variable ahead of time. You may be able to accomplish what you want using the `I()` function, but I'm not sure that it is worth the effort:

```
# contstruct new variable using ifelse function
myData$xSpecial <- ifelse((myData$x >= a | myData$x <= b), x^2, 0)

myReg <- lm( y ~ x + xSpecial, mydata)
```

The `ifelse` function is great if you don't know how it works, take a look at `?ifelse`.

Comment: This looks like a very clean usefull method.
I will try it out.